# Cannot delete a chart series using VBA in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA macro written in Excel 2003 which has worked perfectly well in Excel 2003 and 2007. However, it falls over in Excel 2010 and I cannot tell why.

The macro updates the series in a chart after the user has added or removed data. The first step (after data validation) is to delete all but the first series in the chart.

```
'clear all chart series except for series 1
Do While theChart.SeriesCollection.Count > 1
    theChart.SeriesCollection(2).Delete
Loop
```

Execution halts in the very first iteration of the loop, with the error dialog "Method 'delete' of object 'series' failed."

I thought perhaps the object model had changed in Excel 2010, so I used the macro recorder to record the action of deleting a series:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Plant Feed").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Select
Selection.Delete
```

Running the recorded macro (with Series 3 re-instated obviously) stops on the second line with "Method 'select' of object 'series' failed."

I then added an object variable and some msgbox lines to try to debug the problem:

```
Dim theSeries As Series
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Plant Feed").Activate
MsgBox (ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Name)
Set theSeries = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3)
MsgBox (theSeries.Name)
theSeries.Delete
```

The object variable sets correctly and the message boxes give the right output, but it still falls over on theSeries.delete.

Finally, I repeated all of the above using a brand new chart created in Excel 2010, just in case it was a legacy problem from 2003, but I got the same error.

I am tearing my hair out. I've searched on line for solutions to no avail, which is what led me to this Stack Overflow site. I would appreciate any help that anyone can offer.

Regards,

Darren

Comment: +1 for detailing the steps you've taken so far. Question: Any chance the sheet is protected?

Comment: Thank you Rachel. I wish it was that, even though I would feel a bit silly. Since I posted, I have determined one more thing, which makes me think that it is some sort of 2003 legacy. I don't get the problem if I create a new chart in a new workbook. But new charts in the existing workbook don't work, even if I delete all other charts and VBA modules first. I think I'm going to have to recreate the whole workbook from scratch. <sigh>

Comment: Rachel's +1 didn't work but you desserve it. By the way, you can try to set a breakpoint on the line that raises an error and have a look at `theChart.SeriesCollection(2)` object and check what it is

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it this way instead?

```
For x = theChart.SeriesCollection.Count To 2 Step -1
   theChart.SeriesCollection(x).Delete
Next x
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete items from the beginning of the collection, there will always be a first element, until you deleted them all.

```
Do While theChart.SeriesCollection.Count > 1
     theChart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete   
     'theChart.SeriesCollection(2).Delete    
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you user2169636 and everyone else. It turned out that there was some sort of glitch in the .xlsm file. I exported all the macro modules and rebuilt the chart in a new file, and everything worked. My company was using "Compatibility Mode" at the time and I have heard other reports of this messing up workbooks.